# Delete an application in linux

Tags: 16.04, uninstall

I want to uninstall postman in Ubuntu 16.04. By using  `dpkg --list`, I get all the installed application. Is there a command to find out where the postman is so I can remove it by using `sudo apt-get --purge remove` ?

**Edit**

I use `which postman` to find the location

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          20 Jul  4  2017 postman -> /opt/Postman/Postman*
```

Then I go to that path and `ll`

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j     4096 Jun 30  2017 ./
drwxr-xr-x 16 root         root             4096 Mar  1 11:17 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j    56229 Jun 30  2017 blink_image_resources_200_percent.pak
-rw-r--r--  1 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j       15 Jun 30  2017 content_resources_200_percent.pak
-rw-r--r--  1 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j  9869701 Jun 30  2017 content_shell.pak
-rw-r--r--  1 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j 10127200 Jun 30  2017 icudtl.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j  2574840 Jun 30  2017 libffmpeg.so
-rwxr-xr-x  1 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j 21491192 Jun 30  2017 libnode.so*
-rw-r--r--  1 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j     1060 Jun 30  2017 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j  1350485 Jun 30  2017 LICENSES.chromium.html
drwxr-xr-x  2 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j     4096 Jun 30  2017 locales/
-rw-r--r--  1 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j   367250 Jun 30  2017 natives_blob.bin
-rwxr-xr-x  1 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j 69157920 Jun 30  2017 Postman*
drwxr-xr-x  3 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j     4096 Jun 30  2017 resources/
-rw-r--r--  1 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j   816252 Jun 30  2017 snapshot_blob.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j   159764 Jun 30  2017 ui_resources_200_percent.pak
-rw-r--r--  1 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j        7 Jun 30  2017 version
-rw-r--r--  1 guest-dry22j guest-dry22j    60296 Jun 30  2017 views_resources_200_percent.pak
```

Then I'm lost...

Comment: how about apt search postman

Comment: @Bruni After use `apt search postman`, I get `postal/xenial 0.73+nmu1build1 amd64
  SMTP benchmark - the mad postman`. How can I uninstall it ?

Comment: Does sudo `apt-get --purge remove postal` not work?

Comment: @Bruni No. Here the output `Package 'postal' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 329 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed....`

Comment: what does `which postman` return?

Comment: And how about `dpkg --list | grep postman`

Comment: @Bruni empty result

Comment: So, what is postman? And how did you install it?

Comment: [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). I install it using `apt-get install` if not mistaken..

Comment: I think you already uninstalled it...

Comment: @AryoAdhi No..when I type `postman` on the terminal, it still comes up

Comment: You seem to have installed that software some non-deb-package way. apt *only* knows about deb packages, not snaps, non pip, not rpm, not flatpacks, not source code. How you uninstall depends entirely upon how you originally installed, so search your memory. Until you can provide a bit more information, we cannot help you much.

Comment: @user535733 post edited.

Comment: @AryoAdhi post edited

Comment: @Bruni post edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really remember how I installed postman (maybe I'm not install it by `deb packages`). I delete it using `sudo rm-rf` after get the application's path using `which postman`.

When I type `postman` in terminal again, I get

```
No command 'postman' found, did you mean:
 Command 'postmap' from package 'postfix' (main)
postman: command not found
```

So I assume it get deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, `sudo apt-get --purge remove [package]` doesn't need your input to find a package that was installed either with a package manager (which use `dpkg` to unpack the application) or preinstalled with the OS.  The only time you really need to know where the package is, and where it keeps its configuration, is for manually installed packages (i.e. `*.tar.zip` or similar).

Comment: After use `apt search postman`, I get `postal/xenial 0.73+nmu1build1 amd64
  SMTP benchmark - the mad postman`. How can I uninstall it ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you and to solve it i ran

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/Postman/
```

and

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/postman
```